# Python same code but different inheritence

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two classes (Parent1 and Parent2) that implement some methods. Then I have two classes (Child1 and Child2) that should inherit from their corresponding Parent and implement some functions. The problem is that Child1 and Child2 have the exact same logic so I am hoping someone can point me in the direction of a solution for reusability. I was looking into conditional inheritance but not sure as it is not really a thing in the languages that I come from.

Simple example just to get an idea:

```
# In file1
class Parent1():
    def main_method(self):
        # Parent 1 implementation
        self.arr = [1, 2, 3]

# In file2
class Parent2():
    def main_method(self):
        # Parent 2 implementation
        self.arr = [2, 4, 6]

# In file3
class Child1(Parent1):
    def main_method(self):
        Parent1.main_method(self)
        # Child logic for main_method
        print self.arr

# In file4
class Child2(Parent2):
    def main_method(self):
        Parent2.main_method(self)
        # Child logic for main_method
        print self.arr
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options that come to mind. First, using a Mixin to add functionality through inheritance. I feel like this is the more Pythonic solution. Note that the Mixin will need to be the first inherited class so that it comes first in the MRO (otherwise the `Parent` method will be found).

```
class Parent():
    def main_method(self):
        self.arr = [1, 2, 3]

class MethodMixin():
    def main_method(self):
        super(MethodMixin, self).main_method()
        print(self.arr)

class Child(MethodMixin, Parent): pass
```

I've seen this approach used before with great success. For example, `django-rest-framework` uses this pattern in their [`Viewset`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L150) code.

The second option is to use a metaclass to dynamically add a method to your `Child` classes when they are created.

```
class MethodMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, parents, dct):
        new_cls = super(MethodMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, parents, dct)

        def main_method(self):
            super(new_cls, self).main_method()
            print(self.arr)

        new_cls.main_method = main_method
        return new_cls

class Child(Parent, metaclass=MethodMeta): pass
```

The above snippet uses the Python 3.X metaclass syntax. If you want to use a metaclass in Python 2.X, you have to add it as a class variable named `__metaclass__`. Note that this metaclass approach doesn't scale that well; if you wanted to add in 10 methods with a metaclass, it would be a lot messier than the Mixin alternative.

Comment: Like the look of the mixin solution. Could I then create Child1 that inherits from Parent1 and create Child2 that inherits from Parent2. Then I just mixin to child1 and child2 the methods I need to reuse in both places?

Comment: If you mean `class Child1(MethodMixin, Parent1): pass` and `class Child2(MethodMixin, Parent2): pass`, then yes.

Comment: Two questions. Where do I call the super method to __init__ the parents? If they children implement some differences can I just skip passing and implement those methods?

Comment: @kjonsson Since `MethodMixin` does not contain `__init__`, `super().__init__` in `Child` will resolve to `Parent.__init__`. And, you can always implement a method in `Child` and that will be the first in the MRO.

Comment: So a legit plan: Create child1 and child2 that have some methods, they call init and super and then just let the mixin do all the work from there on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems more logical to me that the Parents becomes childs and vice-versa.Lets . You can do something like

```
class Parent():
    def main_method(self):
        //the child logic in your code
        return self.arr

class Child1(Parent):
    def main_method(self):
       //parent1 logic in your code
       self.arr = [1,2,3]
       Parent.main_method(self)
            print self.arr 

class Child2(Parent):
      def main_method(self):
          //parent2 logic in your code
          self.arr = [2,4,6]
          Parent.main_method(self)
          print self.arr
```

I don't really know if this is meaningful to your actual code but usually the commin logic lays in parent classes while child classes add logic to code. Hope this will help anyway.

Comment: The Parents are drastically different and so are the children. Multiple additional methods between classes and different method implementations. It's from a huge code base that I didn't write and just looking to get rid of some code duplication.

Comment: oh, i thought childs added the same logic to code as you said " The problem is that Child1 and Child2 have the exact same logic"

Comment: Ah your actually right. The problem is that the parents are complicated classes inheriting and implementing QT code and written ages ago by a developer who has since left. Was hoping to fix the code duplication lower down by somehow combining the children into one class and conditionally inheriting or something like that.

Comment: yeah, thats what i meant. if childrens are doing the same stuff, for example "double every digit in self.arr", and parents have complicated logics by which they produce (always for example) a specific array, the parents should inherit from one child which applies the same logic to their different methods. This always all depends on how the code is structured and what functions are actually doing of course.